# Echo javascript function

Tags: php

I am tryaing to to make this echo work, but i cant get the grip of it

```
    echo '<script> 
 function replaceWithImgLinks(txt) {
var linkRegex = /([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png))/gi;
return txt.replace(linkRegex, "<a href="$1" target="_blank"><img class="sml" src="$1" /></a><br />");
}
var newHTML = replaceWithImgLinks($(".ms").html());
$(".ms").html(newHTML);';

                echo "</script>";
```

What am i doing wrong? i think i got something wrong with my " ' .

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here... What is the regex supposed to match?

Answer (score 0):

There was a couple of issues.  I started by just running it in JavaScript until I got it to work, then moved it into PHP (for the sake of sanity).

```
<?php

print '
    <script> 
        function replaceWithImgLinks(txt) {
            var linkRegex = /([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)?(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png))/gi;
            return txt.replace(linkRegex, "<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\"><img class=\"sml\" src=\"$1\" /></a><br />");
        }
        var newHTML = replaceWithImgLinks($(".ms").html());
        $(".ms").html(newHTML);
    </script>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the regex be something like:

```
(^|\b)((https?:)?\/\/[^\s]*?\.(jpe?g|png|gif))(\b|$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/If1FMBfPMBYz-T0v)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be echo'ing scripts, especially scripts in script tags. I would seriously look into just using your back end to fetch, then use an asynchronous technology that fetches data parsed JSON. That way you can call your scripts normally.